# VPN disables Internet connection sharing ICU

Tags: windows-8.1, vpn

I've been having this problem with my VPN. normally I share my Internet connection with other laptop and ICU works well but when I connect to VPN on my computer, the other laptop won't have Internet connection. I searched everywhere and couldn't find anything to solve my problem. I also set `8.8.8.8` as DNS in my IPv4 settings and the laptop.

Comment: There is no good answer to your query, other than to add a second network card. When you establish a VPN connection, its like your local machine is directly connected to the remote network, and is no longer connected to your local network at all.

Comment: I do have a second network card. my Wireless internet is shared with wired LAN port and laptop is connected to that port.

Comment: then set up your routing so that the wired interface is used only to reach the VPN'd network, enable split tunneling on your VPN client, and configure your system to do everything LAN related on the wifi interface.